# Variable setting a variable to be used

Tags: python, renpy

I've been working with Ren'Py engine, a simple engine for visual novels using Python to do stuff.
I came across this problem and dunno what to do, anybody can gimme a hand?

**bar:**
    StaticValue(**variable**, **value**)

**Bar** creates a bar representing **variable**, with the maximum value of **value**. I will not mention **value** further, as it is irrelevant to my question.

I am trying to use **Used** as **variable**, meaning **Used** is variable being represented. 
**Used** however, doesn't have value in integer. **Used** is a variable with a value of **"Skill1"** or **"Skill2"**

**Skill1** and **Skill2** are variables with integers, and THEY are the ones I want to represent by the **bar**.

So, what I want in the end is StaticValue(**Skill1**, **value**) OR StaticValue(**Skill2**, **value**), depending on the value of **Used** (There is If predated to define this).

Another try at the explanation:

What Python THIKS RIGHT NOW:

bar: StaticValue(**Used**). Bar is supposed to represent variable **Used**.

What I WANT Python TO THINK:

bar: StaticValue(**Used**). **Used** is a variable with a value of **"Skill1"**. Bar is supposed to represent **Skill1**, as this results in StaticValue(**Skill1**).

I took a second try on that explanation, hopefully better now.
Any help is appreciated.

---

As a reaction to User2589273's answer, for better overview:
The 4) would be exactly what I want/need, but it gives me unspecified error now. 
What I did was:

```
python:
    if InTeaching == "Skill1":
        UsedSkill = "1"
    elif InTeaching == "Skill2":
        UsedSkill = "2"
    elif InTeaching == "Skill3":
        UsedSkill = "3"
    else:
        pass
    dict = {1: 'Skill1Value', 2: 'Skill2Value', 3: 'Skill3Value'}
```

Followed by:

```
bar:
    value StaticValue(dict[UsedSkill], 10)
```

So if InTeaching == Skill1, UsedSkill will be set to 1. Later, in the bar, UsedSkill will be matched by the dictionary to fill in Skill1Value, variable that is supposed to be present in the StaticValue. 
It works in my head, but python gives me error on line with "bar:".

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please take some time to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: You have so many words yet your question is totally unclear. Try improving your question by separating out sections.
- Your code. - It's expected behaviour. - How it fails. If there are error messages also add that to your question.

Comment: Still extremely unclear what the specific problem is when you try to code this.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are asking but here are my four guesses:

1) assigning a variable using a string name / string from other variable:

```
dict = {'variable_name':value}
add to locals().update(dict)
```

2) Supplying an argument consisting as two parts which have already been pre-defined:

```
a = [b,c]
barstuffs(a)
```

3) something to do with making a class that can take on certain values:
Have a read through https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

4) dictionary use:

```
dict = {0: 'skill1', 1: 'skill2'}
used = 1 
dict[used]  will give 'skill2'
```